# SharePoint Online Multi Tiered Hub Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, office-365-groups, hub-site

Is it possible within SharePoint Online using only Modern SharePoint sites to have a Hub site acting as a 'spoke' of another Hub?

For example if you had four Modern site collections where Site A is Hub A, Site B is Hub B, and sites C/D are not Hubs, can Site B have Site A as it's Hub while also serving as the Hub for sites C & D?

Testing in my own tenant on an E1 plan indicates this isn't possible as in the SP Admin center under Hub settings it's one or the other depending on whether the site has been designated a Hub, but I'm wondering if there's some way to do it by manipulating things under the hood via scripts or Azure deployed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested hub sites aren't supported yet, though the request has been on [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33428857-nested-hub-sites) for a while. For now, we're stuck with manually linking hub sites together, which is a far different experience than what an actual nesting of hub sites could be.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the answer, thanks for confirming.